# Android Studio: Unfortunately, app has stopped

Tags: java, android

My android calculator app seems to be failing at the moment, can anyone please fix it? I searched everywhere, but none of them seem to be working.

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.koki.customizablecalculator" 
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java** file:

```
    package com.example.koki.customizablecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText Scr;
    private float NumberBf;
    private String Operation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button0);


        int idList[] = {R.id.button0,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4,R.id.button5,
                R.id.button6,R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.buttonDot,R.id.buttonMul,
                R.id.buttonDiv,R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,
        };
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**content_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AC"
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSub" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:background="#10E0F8"
        android:allowUndo="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonAdd" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:background="#FE9A2E"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:background="#FE9A2E"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:background="#FE9A2E"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonMul"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMul"
        android:background="#FE9A2E"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonC" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/buttonEq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#1B9863" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Could you post the error log you are getting? Without it will be hard to help

Comment: `button0` is a `TextView`. You can't cast it to `EditText`

Comment: Nice job of formatting your post.  Please post an error log, it helps others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an EditText that you don't have.

Either in your XML change your TextView to an EditText

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />
```

OR Change

```
private EditText Scr;
```

To

```
private TextView Scr;
```

And

```
Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button0);
```

To

```
Scr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button0);
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much! :)